# Navigate S3 bucket using Lambda Edge function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have a Lambda Edge function on a Cloudfront distribution that makes an API call to my backend, and I want to use the response of this API call to navigate an S3 bucket. So say I have an S3 bucket with two directories which each contain different static sites, and depending on the result of the API call, it will serve either one or the other static sites. Is this possible in an Edge Lambda function to navigate within an S3 bucket and serve the contents of this navigation? If not, I could have multiple S3 buckets and separate the static sites that way.

In either case, how would I got about directing traffic to different S3 buckets or directories within an S3 bucket in a Lambda Edge function? I cannot use redirect, since the URL that the user sees should be the same in either case.

Answer (score 0):

You can update `request.origin.s3` object in event data to set different origin than original then return modified event data

Here including sample lambdaEdge function to route to different s3 websites based on API response

```
const axios = require('axios');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

    // Make an HTTP request to your API Gateway endpoint
    const response = await axios.get('YOUR_API_GATEWAY_ENDPOINT');
        
    // Update the request to use the determined S3 bucket URL
    request = Object.assign(request, {
            origin: {
                s3: {
                    domainName: response.s3BucketUrl
                }      
            }
        });

    return request;
};
```